# update UI with animation synchronously or in serial queue

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation, nsoperationqueue

I have custom build menu which pushes or pops views. for example menu1 pushes a view. if menu2 is pressed the removes previous view and show other view.
pushing and popping are animated. how to serially update/push/pop views with animation? it should no ignore any menu selection

i have used `dispatch_queue_t` and `NSOperationQueue` to no avail as if it ignores uiview animation. the `self.uiOperationQueue` has 1 as max concurrent operation.

```
[self.uiOperationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self updateViewsForSelection:menuType];
    });
}];
```

with dispatch queue:

```
self.uiUpdateQueue = dispatch_queue_create("ui-updateQueue", NULL);
dispatch_async(self.uiUpdateQueue, ^{
        [self updateViewsForSelection:menuType];
});
```

so basically the `[self updateViewsForSelection:menuType]` is called with different menu and uiview animation with duration. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible to add `animation blocks` into an array and execute them one after another using the `completion block`

```
-(void)executeAnimationsInArray:(NSArray *)array atIndex:(int)index
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:array[index] completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (index < array.count - 1)
        {
            [self executeAnimationsInArray:array atIndex:index+1];
        }
    }];

}
```

It can be used like

```
id block1 = ^(void) {
    imgView.frame = CGRectOffset(imgView.frame, 10, 10);
};
id block2 = ^(void) {
    imgView.frame = CGRectOffset(imgView.frame, -10, -10);
};

[self executeAnimationsInArray:@[block1, block2] atIndex:0];
```

Comment: currently I'm collecting the pressed menu button event in an array and executing one at a time after animation completion block. still i cannot resolve the issue. i think i'm not going in the right direction.

Comment: What is the issue you are getting now?

Comment: still i have broken views. I'm using constraints for views, and there it says cannot parse because view doesn't have superview. I'm currently debugging. I will provide further info.

Comment: i had forgotten to include in pop view function and now it works. thanks